# при сборке g++ возникает ошибка

Tags: makefile, g++

```
In file included from /home/user/gcc/gcc_n/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/cp/except.c:1005:
cfns.gperf:101:1: error: ‘const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned int)’ redeclared inline with ‘gnu_inline’ attribute
cfns.gperf:26:14: note: ‘const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned int)’ previously declared here
cfns.gperf:26:14: warning: inline function ‘const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned int)’ used but never defined
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1058: cp/except.o] Ошибка 1
make[3]: выход из каталога «/home/user/gcc/gcc_n/comp/gcc»
make[2]: *** [Makefile:4157: all-stage1-gcc] Ошибка 2
make[2]: выход из каталога «/home/user/gcc/gcc_n/comp»
make[1]: *** [Makefile:21520: stage1-bubble] Ошибка 2
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/user/gcc/gcc_n/comp»
make: *** [Makefile:886: all] Ошибка 2
```

Может кто то подсказать что не так?

upd: ниже по ссылке применил патч

после запуска сборки повторно:

```
/home/user/gcc/gcc_n/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/doc/gcc.texi:88: warning: @tex должен появляться только в начале строки
/home/user/gcc/gcc_n/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/doc/gcc.texi:208: нет парной «@end tex»
/home/user/gcc/gcc_n/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/doc/gcc.texi:208: нет парной «@end multitable»
/home/user/gcc/gcc_n/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/doc/gcc.texi:208: нет парной «@end titlepage»
make[3]: *** [Makefile:4352: doc/gcc.info] Ошибка 1
make[3]: выход из каталога «/home/user/gcc/gcc_n/comp/gcc»
make[2]: *** [Makefile:4157: all-stage1-gcc] Ошибка 2
make[2]: выход из каталога «/home/user/gcc/gcc_n/comp»
make[1]: *** [Makefile:21520: stage1-bubble] Ошибка 2
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/user/gcc/gcc_n/comp»
make: *** [Makefile:886: all] Ошибка 2
```

Comment: Выглядит будто вы собираете старый код новым компилятором. Какая версия GCC собирает это?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6), как понизить версию g++ до 4,8, или как собрать ее нуля?

Comment: Зачем вам собирать такой старый компилятор?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, один из проектов который нужно собрать просит g++ версии ниже 5

Comment: Почему не поставить бинарный пакет с компилятором нужной версии?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy так вот я и пытаюсь это сделать, только собрать из исходников, как поставить бинарный пакет?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy можете обьяснить как понизить версию до 4,8?

Comment: Примените [патч](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commitdiff;h=ec1cc0263f156f70693a62cf17b254a0029f4852) к исходникам. Можно руками. После этого ваша текущая сборка должна заработать.

Comment: Если  вдруг вы не хотите возиться со сборкой, можно поставить докер c debian jessie внутри. Там будет GCC 4.8 (или 4.9). В этом докере можно сделать нужную вам компиляцию без лишней возни.

Comment: Главная идея - старые проекты собирать в их родных средах. Докер - самое легковесное решение. Или можно виртуалку создать - с ней может оказаться проще.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy как потом использовать проект собраный на виртуалке, на хостовой машине?

Comment: Перенести результаты сборки. Если с этим трудности, то эксплуатировать проект прямо в виртуалке. В купили себе много хлопот, если не собираетесь портировать проект в свежий Дебиан.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, вопрос не про это, нужно вообщем gcc-4.8 настроить,можете мануал какойто дать?

Comment: Я дал выше патч, который нужно применить к исходникам, чтобы они собрались. Вы его попробовали уже?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да патч применил, перезапустил сборку, но опять ошибки, добавил их в вопрос